# Getting the leave page alert every time,when I press buttons to retrieving the messages and values using ajax in servlets in client side chat?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

In my jsp page,I displayed the div which contains text area,text field and send button only if I got sessionId != "null".

Also I am having an confirmation alert box for closing the window to logout the session...

but I am getting the same alert every time if I trying to retrive the values of sessionId,userId,etc.. or  to send the message to sever when pressing startChat or send button...
In my Jsp page,

```
<div id="login">
<form id="indexForm" name="indexForm" action="LoginAction" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="fname" class="fontStyle">First Name :</td>
        <td id="fvalue"><input type="text" id="firstname"
            name="firstname" /></td>
        <td id="lname" class="fontStyle">Last Name :</td>
        <td id="lvalue"><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" id="err1" style="color: red">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="email_id" class="fontStyle">Email Id&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /></td>
        <td id="sub" class="fontStyle">Subject
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" id="err2" style="color: red">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <center><a id="button" href="javascript:getValues();">Start
        chat</a></center>
        </td>
        <td>
        <center><a id="button" href="javascript:logout();">Stop
        chat</a></center>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</table>

</form>
</div>

<div style="display: none;" id="div">
<div><textarea id="textarea" rows="10"></textarea></div>
<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="msg" class="fontStyle">message :</td>
        <td id="msgvalue"><input size="40" type="text" id="message"
            onkeydown="enterKey()" /></td>
        <td style="width: 5%;"></td>
        <td><!-- <input type="button" value="send" onclick="sendMessage()" /> -->
        <a id="button3" href="javascript:sendMessage();">Send</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

In my JavaScript,

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {

      return  "Are you Sure want to LOGOUT the session ?";
};

window.onunload = function () {

        if((sessionId != null)&&(sessionId!="null")&& (sessionId != ""))
            logout();
};

function sendMessage(){

    message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    document.getElementById("message").innerText = "";
    try
    {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            //alert("Status : "+xmlhttp.status+"\nreadyState : "+xmlhttp.readyState);
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {


                var checkMsg = decodeURIComponent(xmlhttp.responseText.toString());
                if(checkMsg != "null" && checkMsg != null){
                    //document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML +=  checkMsg;
                    if(textarea.value == "")
                        textarea.value = checkMsg;
                    else
                        textarea.value += "\n"+ checkMsg  ;
                }
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST","SendMessageAction?sessionId="+sessionId+"&userId="+userId+"&securekey="+secureKey+"&message="+encodeURIComponent(message)+"&sid"+Math.random(),true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err.description);
    }
}
```

In my Servlet,

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        msg = request.getParameter("message");
        //System.out.println("msg -----> : "+msg);
        seckey = request.getParameter("securekey");
        uid = request.getParameter("userId");
        sessionId = request.getParameter("sessionId");
        //counter =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("counter"));
        counter = 1;
        protocol = ApplicationInfo.flexProtocol;

        message = new SendMessage();
        message.send(msg, seckey, uid, sessionId, counter, protocol);

        CustomerInfo customer = ApplicationInfo.customerDetails.get(uid);

        out.print(customer.getMessage());
        //System.out.println("msgDecoded -----> : "+msg);

    }
```

Help me...I don't need to get the alert every time, except I am closing the Browsing window...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event `onbeforeunload` is triggered when we do one of the following.

```
Close the current window.
Navigate to another location by entering a new address or selecting a Favorite.
Click an anchor that refers to another document.
Invoke the anchor.click method.
Invoke the document.write method.
Invoke the document.close method.
Invoke the window.close method.
Invoke the window.navigate or NavigateAndFind method.
Invoke the location.replace method.
Invoke the location.reload method.
Specify a new value for the location.href property.
Submit a form to the address specified in the ACTION attribute via the INPUT type=submit control, or invoke the form.submit method.
Invoke the window.open method, providing the possible value _self for the window name.
Invoke the document.open method.
Click the Back, Forward, Refresh, or Home button.
```

[MSDN description for onbeforeunload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is,

I am using the anchor tag for the events in the java script instead of button.
So " window.onbeforeunload " considers the event as a new address . Now I changed the anchor tag in to the buttons and working fine..